# devise gem vs devise_token_auth gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, devise, token

I would like to know which gem(`DEVISE` OR `DEVISE_AUTH_TOKEN`) is better to use with react. Please also help me to find good resource to implement these authentication using react.

Comment: I don't think this type of questions are welcomed on this site, you better ask how to solve a particular problem rather than asking an opinion. Concerning finding good recources, just try something, if you get a problem then ask here, community will try to help you with that. You feel me? It's the other way around. There are plenty other resources on internet where opinion questions are welcomed, but  not here. Better remove this question.

Comment: @seethrough https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480626/devise-gem-is-not-working-properly-with-react-http-origin-header-http-loca can you help regading the problem specified in above link.

Comment: Use JWT for frontend react app with backend rails app

Comment: @SanjuBMyh can you through some more light on JWT.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-to-using-jwt-in-rails/ this might help you